# Data retrieval in Node js

Tags: node.js

I was having problem in extracting data from variable doc while working on a Node js project.

Here's the snippet

```
collection.find({}, Function(err, doc));
```

Assuming a field present in variable doc namely userid, how can I retrieve its value and print it on console. I need to get the data on current working file, without being redirected to some other page

Answer (score 0):

You receive an array of elements asynchronously so you need to loop them with something like this:

With MongoDB native driver:

```
collection.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
        if (doc != null) {
            console.log(doc);
        } else {
            db.close();
        }
    });
});
```

With Monk you can use the [stream feature](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#streaming):

```
collection.find({}, {stream: true}).each(function(doc) {
    if (doc != null) {
        console.log(doc);
    } else {
        db.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: 'docs.each()' is not working as "Object [object Object] has no method 'each' " is getting printed on console

Comment: What MongoDB module are you using?

Comment: Mongo DB version 2.1.2 and monk